# why dwa don't considering heading diff as a score anymore?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I am using dwa for a holomic robot. Since heading towards the global plan is important in my work. In the old trajectory planner, the total score is 0.3*heading diff+goal+target+occ. But in the new dwa planner, it uses alignment cost and goal front instead. Why the new planner uses these 2 factors? And my robot fails to head with the global plan. It looks really ugly in real world!
Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287942/why-dwa-don%27t-considering-heading-diff-as-a-score-anymore?/) by [xiaoyuanzh](https://answers.ros.org/users/34538/xiaoyuanzh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-04-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-04-09**:
Please provide links and version numbers for the packages you're referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It uses alignment function instead. But it can't calculate as well as I wish. May I be able to rewrite a costfunction class like heading diff and add it to critic vector?

---

Originally posted by [xiaoyuanzh](https://answers.ros.org/users/34538/xiaoyuanzh/) with karma: 16 on 2018-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0